# Recognizing multiple faces (eigenfaces opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc

I'm creating facial recognition program that uses eigenfaces method implemented in OpenCV 2.4.8.
I have training set of three faces (10 pictures each), also i have 3 pictures of people trained in training set. So far program works very well, recognition is 100% correct.
However, I have tried to solve different problem with my program.. I have edited 3 test photos so that i have put those 3 photos in one photo, and that photo is my test sample. 
Program doesn't recognize anyone in that example.

So my conclusion would be that eigenfaces recognizer can recognize only one face per photo. Is that correct?

Is there some kind of eignefaces support to recognize multiple faces in one photo?

Comment: detect faces, apply recognition to those rectangles one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV face recognition can only work on a face at a time. Your program cannot recognize anyone from the test image since the euclidean distance it computes from the test image and your training set is simply too high. You would need to implement a face detection algorithm if you want to test an image with several faces.